# removing multiple document's references using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, reference, middleware, documents

I'm currently trying to remove multiple documents references (objectId) when i'm removing those documents.

So this is my code to remove multiple documents and their references:

```
Comment.find({parentCommentId: req.params.id}).stream()
.on('data', function (comment) {
    comment.remove(function (err, result) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        console.log(result);
    })
})
.on('error', function(err){
    // handle error
})
.on('end', function(){
     res.status(200).json({
     title: 'Comments deleted'
     });
});
```

(this is the middleware i use)

```
schema.post('remove', function (comment) {
    Project.findById(comment.project, function (err, project) {
        if(err){
            console.log('error : '+ err)
        }
        project.comments.pull(comment);
        project.save();
    });
    User.findById(comment.user, function (err, user) {
        if(err){
            console.log('error : '+ err)
        }
        user.comments.pull(comment);
        user.save();
    });
});
```

At the moment i tried multiple things but i kinda got stuck: it removes all the documents i wanted but it always only removes the first document's reference and keeps the other ones.

at this point i don't really understand why.

Have a good day : )

Comment: You should be using [`.findByIdAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) as well as the [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator of MongoDB. These allow you to easily remove multiple entries from an array. Also you need to understand how to use callbacks and/or promises. Right now your "post remove" hook is not waiting for the other methods to complete before returning, and you do need to do that.

Comment: @NeilLunn  ok thx, i used .findByIdAndUpdate() and it worked :)